# keyboard issue in iOS - codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I have a addEvent form. Here there are a no. of fields to be filled by user. There are textfields, pickers, textArea etc. When i have focus on the textfield in the top of the form, the keyboard works good. I notice the done button in the keypad is at the bottom of keyboard. But as soon as the textfield or textArea at the bottom of the form get focused, the keyboard with the done button at the top of keyboard is shown. After the done botton is clicked, there is the white blank space at the top of form that i think the height keyboard occupies before.

update 1: descriptionTextArea gives the issue.

```
f.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

Label eventImage = new Label();
TextField eventNameTextField = new TextField();

Button uploadImg = new Button(theme.getImage("uploadImg.png"));
//uploadImg actionListener code is skipped here
Container eventNameContainer = new Container(new BorderLayout());
Label maxSizeLabel = new Label("Max size 1mb");

Container wrapUploadIconAndMsg = new Container(new BorderLayout());
wrapUploadIconAndMsg.add(BorderLayout.WEST, uploadImg);
wrapUploadIconAndMsg.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, maxSizeLabel);
eventNameContainer.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, (BoxLayout.encloseY(eventImage, wrapUploadIconAndMsg)));
eventNameContainer.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, (eventNameTextField));

Picker startDate = new Picker();
Picker startTime = new Picker();

Container startContainer = GridLayout.encloseIn(2, startDate, startTime);
Label timeIcon = new Label(iconEvent);
Container wrapStartContainer = BoxLayout.encloseX(FlowLayout.encloseCenter(timeIcon), (startContainer));

Label timeIconInvisible = new Label(iconEvent);
timeIconInvisible.setVisible(false);

Picker endDate = new Picker();
Picker endTime = new Picker();

Container endContainer = GridLayout.encloseIn(2, endDate, endTime);
Container wrapEndContainer = BoxLayout.encloseX((timeIconInvisible), FlowLayout.encloseCenterBottom(endContainer));

Label descriptionIcon = new Label();
descriptionIcon.setIcon(iconDescription);

TextArea descriptionTextArea = new TextArea();
descriptionTextArea.setRows(4);
descriptionTextArea.setMaxSize(240);
descriptionTextArea.setVerticalAlignment(Label.TOP);

Container descriptionContainer = new Container(new BorderLayout());
descriptionContainer.add(BorderLayout.WEST, descriptionIcon);
descriptionContainer.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, descriptionTextArea);
Container wrapEventContainer = BoxLayout.encloseY(eventNameContainer, wrapStartContainer, wrapEndContainer, descriptionContainer);

f.add(wrapEventContainer);
f.revalidate();
```

1)initial form:

[image]

2)keyboard with done button at the bottom of keyboard (works fine here) -textfield at top of the form is used.

[image]

3)keyboard with done button at the top of keyboard(problem arise after done is touched)

[image]

4)the issue after done is pressed. (blank white area is seen) I think its height equals to the height of keyboard

[image]

Comment: Odd. Can you provide some details about the layout of the form and how to reproduce this? This doesn't happen to me with a very simple test case so do you have any special layout, nested containers, animations or something else?

Comment: We'll try to reproduce this in a test case, can you please file an issue?